# Can't make this random number generator to work properly

Tags: python, loops, random

I'm trying to make a random number generator and return the random generated number, but this code returns all the numbers before the random number. How can I return only the last string printed?

```
import random

from_num = int(input('Generate a random number:\nFrom:'))
to_num = int(input('To:'))

for num in range(random.randrange(from_num,to_num+1)):
    if True:
        print(f'Random number: {num}')
    else:
        print('You did not entered valid min/max numbers')
```

Output for `from_num = 0` and `to_num = 20` by exemple, instead of '11' can return any number between these two given.

```
Random number: 0
Random number: 1
Random number: 2
Random number: 3
Random number: 4
Random number: 5
Random number: 6
Random number: 7
Random number: 8
Random number: 9
Random number: 10
Random number: 11
```

Comment: If you only want a single value, why on earth do you have a for loop?

Comment: Or on any planet for that matter.

Comment: Also, your `else` clause will never get executed with `True` as your if statement condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following to the comments above, just print the random value, without iterating on anything:

```
import random

from_num = int(input('Generate a random number:\nFrom:'))
to_num = int(input('To:'))

if from_num > to_num:
    print('You did not entered valid min/max numbers')
    return

random_num = random.randrange(from_num,to_num+1):
print(f'Random number: {random_num}')
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution as it drops the range check in the original example.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
for num in range(random.randrange(from_num,to_num+1)):
    if True:
        print(f'Random number: {num}')
    else:
        print('You did not entered valid min/max numbers')
```

with :

```
ran_num = random.randint(from_num,to_num)
print("Random number is " + str(ran_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a loop?

```
import random

from_num = int(input('Generate a random number:\nFrom:'))
to_num = int(input('To:'))

if to_num > from_num:
    ran_number = random.randrange(from_num,to_num+1)
    print(f'Random number: {ran_number}')
else:
    print('You did not entered valid min/max numbers')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make it so the user can pick the range then i don't know but if you want it random on a button click then heres the code first do this
 `int Rnumber;`
then

```
TextView RandomNumber;
```

The "RandomNumber" You must make a textview that has the id RandomNumber

Oh! And before i forget you need a button with the id GenRan.
Then put in this code

```
Button GenRan;
```

Insert this code

```
Random Number;
```

Then this code

```
  Number = new Random();
            Rnumber = Number.nextInt(1000);
            RandomNumber.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber));
```

and you're good to go and btw the "(1000)" is the max number it can generate so its from 1-1000 you can change that if you want